# Hibernate ID Generation with Sequence in Oracle - Single trip to DB

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

In hibernate, when `sequence` is used as generation strategy for insertion, it first queries DB for next value from sequence and then sets it in the entity. After that this entity is persisted in db. So to sum up two queries are executed.

**Flow:**

- Hibernate fetches sequence's next value
- Hibernate sets the fetched value as ID of your entity
- Hibernate persists the entity, with it's ID being set in the query

**Query:**

`select
        CUSTOM_SEQUENCE.nextval 
    from
        dual`

then this value is used in insert statement.

**Question:**

Is there anyway, we could generate a query like `INSERT INTO foobar
(foo_id, foo)
VALUES (FOOBAR_SEQUENCE.nextval, 'bar');` in hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use the Hibernate [seqhilo generator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-hilo) which will avoid round trips to the Database by asking for a larger sequence and handling the ID internally.

Comment: Is hi/lo strategy safe in cluster env or in a scenario where database table can be updated by multiple applications simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, as Hibernate is _reserving_ sequence range to Oracle.

Comment: As per your answer and hibernate docs,  Hilo does avoid a round trip to DB. Is there any way to generate id at database side using query like I have mentioned in the question, that would leave most of the work on database side which I think db can handle very efficiently.
Although I could use hilo, there are few pitfalls of this strategy like https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3608

Comment: Looks like Hilo is best strategy if I chose my low and high value carefully. If these value change in future then it may cause collisions.